# C++ ADO Excel record deletion

Tags: c++, excel, ado

I am doing excel file operations with C++ ADO.

I could select, update and insert.
It cannot be deleted.

```
enter code here

CString strFile = _T("C:\\temp\\sample.xlsx");
CString s;
try
{
    CString strCon;
    strCon.Format( _T( "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=%s;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 xml" ) , strFile );
    con.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection));
    con->Open(_bstr_t(strCon), "", "", adConnectUnspecified);

    _RecordsetPtr rs;
    rs.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Recordset));
    rs->CursorLocation = adUseClient;
    rs->Open(_variant_t( "SELECT * FROM [test$] WHERE [ID]='A1'" ), con.GetInterfacePtr(), adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText );
    
    if( !rs->GetadoEOF() )
    {
        rs->Delete(adAffectCurrent);
        rs->Close();
    }
}
catch(_com_error& e)
{
    s=e.ErrorMessage();
}
if( con != NULL ) con->Close();
con = NULL;
```

Exception occurs in delete

Comment: *Exception occurs in delete* -- What is the exact error message?

Comment: The message is "エラーを特定できません" (Unspecified error)